# addListenerForSingleValueEvent not responding

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

`query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener())`
function inside it not working.
If query is not found in firebase Db, it should get new query and display it with text search query not found.

But all inside it is not working

```
TextView search_text=findViewById(R.id.search_text);
        if(search_query!=null)
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
               .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
               .orderByChild("imageName")
               .startAt(search_query).endAt(search_query +"\uf8ff");
        else query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
                    .orderByChild("imageName");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    search_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    search_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    search_text.setText(search_query+" not found");
                    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                            .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
                            .orderByChild("imageName");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WallpaperItem>()
                .setQuery(query, WallpaperItem.class)
                .build();
```

The function inside the addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not responding.

Comment: What is the error? *or* What is the supposed behavior according to which this is not working?

Comment: The function inside the addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not responding.

Comment: Have you tried to print `databaseError.toException()`, what is the output? Please add your database structure and please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView search_text=findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    if(search_query!=null)
    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
           .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
           .orderByChild("imageName")
           .startAt(search_query).endAt(search_query +"\uf8ff");
    else query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
                .orderByChild("imageName");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                search_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                search_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                search_text.setText(search_query+" not found");
                query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference(Common.STR_WALLPAPER)
                        .orderByChild("imageName");
            }
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WallpaperItem>()
            .setQuery(query, WallpaperItem.class)
            .build();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Put option and adapter inside addListenerForSingleValueEvent